# SpaCy Pex can't find model?

Tags: spacy, python-pex

I'm trying to bundle SpaCy into a pex file as detailed in their docs [here](https://spacy.io/usage#executable).  I have successfully built the pex file, and am now trying to run a simple python script that runs SpaCy against a passed in text file.  I import SpaCy and try to load the `en_core_web_trf` model as shown below.

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_trf")
```

I try to run the script with the `spacy.pex` executable output by their tool and am getting:

```
Can't find model 'en_core_web_trf'. It doesn't seem to be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory
```

I have tried to download the model by running:

```
./spacy.pex -m spacy download en_core_web_trf
```

but that doesn't seem to work either.

I have tried to download the model directly from their github page [here](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/tag/en_core_web_trf-3.5.0). and extract the tar archive to the same directory as the `spacy.pex` file and renamed the resulting folder to `en_core_web_trf` and instead get:

```
[E053] Could not read config file from en_core_web_trf/config.cfg
```

Looking through that model folder, I found that there is a nested `config.cfg` in the subfolder `en_core_web_trf`.  I tried moving that folder up and still no dice.

How do I package the model so that I can use it with the `spacy.pex` file and run scripts with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you install the model in your terminal using this:

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_trf
```

After that you can use the following code to load the model:

```
import spacy
import en_core_web_trf
nlp = en_core_web_trf.load()
```

Probably you will receive this error:

```
ValueError: [E002] Can't find factory for 'transformer' for language English (en). This usually happens when spaCy calls `nlp.create_pipe` with a custom component name that's not registered on the current language class. If you're using a Transformer, make sure to install 'spacy-transformers'. If you're using a custom component, make sure you've added the decorator `@Language.component` (for function components) or `@Language.factory` (for class components).
```

So make sure you install `spacy-transformers` too in your terminal using `pip install spacy-transformers`. With the final code like this:

```
import spacy
import spacy_transformers
import en_core_web_trf
nlp = en_core_web_trf.load()
```